# Bootstrap 4 Navbar Toggle Icon Doesn't Work

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I have a HTML file below. When I make the browser smaller, I can see the hamburger menu, but when I click on it, nothing happens.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
            <a href="/" class="navbar-brand">Homepage</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <!-- left side -->
                </ul>

                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <!-- right side -->
                    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                        <li class="nav-item ml-3 mr-3">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">{{user.username}}</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'logout'%}">Log out</a>
                        </li>
                    {% else %}
                        <li class="nav-item ml-3 mr-3">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'login'%}">Log In</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'signup' %}">Sign Up</a>
                        </li>
                    {% endif %}
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How stupid my mistake was!
I forgot to load bootstrap js files!

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-7+zCNj/IqJ95wo16oMtfsKbZ9ccEh31eOz1HGyDuCQ6wgnyJNSYdrPa03rtR1zdB" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

to the bottom of your `<body>`. Further reading about [bootstrap CDN](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/getting-started/introduction/)